# Least upper bound rationals vs reals

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Rudin's PMA. 
Earlier he defines a set: $A = \{p \in Q: p^2 < 2\}$ and $B = \{p \in Q: p^2 > 2\}$

Later, in an example he states that A has no least upper bound as the upper bounds of A are B and B has no smallest number. And hence, "A has no least upper bound in Q." And vice versa for teh set B

My question is: A and B will have a least upper bound/highest upper bound but only in the set $R$. And that bounding number is $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes, only do not forget, that in Rudin $\sqrt{2}$ is Dedekind cut.

Comment: The upper bounds of $A$ are not $B$, they are "half" of $B$ (the elements of $B$ that are positive).